# why is compiling with xCode so much slower than with Eclipse for Android?

Tags: android, iphone, xcode

I have an app available for iPhone and Android.

While compiling and linking until the app starts on Android it takes only a couple of seconds. Doing the same on xCode (both on a MacBook Pro) it now takes about 3 hours with xCode 4.4.  With previous xCodes it took around 2 hours.

The code is very similar for both platforms and has some data classes with around 20k lines (which I can't store in a DB or in a file, since they require computation depending on the envorinment)

Many thanks

Comment: My codebases usually exist of far more than 20k lines, and it compiles in less than 5 seconds ...
So, I think you're doing something really wrong.

What do you store in your classes, and why does it depend on the environment?

Comment: is there any way to find out which file is currently being compiled when it says for example "Compiling 98 out of 168 source files", then I can check which files take long time? Also even if I do not change anything on the files, recomiling takes also very long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have anti-virus running on the system that takes a long time?  I am running Kaspersky on my MacBook and sometimes when I save a file, I will get the beachball for 10 seconds and sometimes for up to 5 minutes.  I turn Kaspersky off when I'm working with Xcode and hope that I remember to turn it back on when I'm surfing.

Comment: no I do not have anthing else running. The CPUs run at 100%. But it just takes forever - it's in total about 100k lines of code. That should not be too much I would expect since other apps I would expect are even larger...